# How to optimize 'class name' in Android XML Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using some custom components in my project for that I am using following code.

```
 <view
  class="com.android.mypackage.myclass" 
  id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@android:drawable/button"
  android:padding="10dip"
  />
```

Its working perfectly fine, I am using this code near about 35 times in my application. so while creating new clone application from same project, I need to update package name in 35 places. Is there any way to reduce these efforts? I had tried with "class="@string/class_name" but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put your custom views in your original package, and just put them in another package.
You can also put them as following pic.
[image]
And the code in layout xml is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<MyView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It is more convenient.

Comment: Yes, got your point thanks a lot for your help, you saved my lot of energy:)

Comment: Just a notice : if you put your classes in android.widget package, take care not to conflict with an already-existing file in the SDK, or your app won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No. You only have the alternative to write:

```
<com.android.mypackage.myclass
    id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/button"
    android:padding="10dip" />
```

`class="@string/class_name` does not work, because the name of the class must be constant and be available at compile time while generating Java code from XML.

`@string/class_name` means that the value of the field `R.string.class_name` is "dynamically" read while runtime.